# PHP unlink() content still appearing

Tags: php, html, angular

I have an Angular front end and PHP back end for my website. I remove a couple images from Angulars assets folder using PHP and its unlink function:

```
$myFile = "../src/assets/images/".$name;
unlink($myFile) or die("Couldn't delete file");
```

The images are getting deleted, they are no longer present in the images folder when i check. However, the angular application is still displaying them, despite emptying the cache and hard reloading of the page. I even made changes to the angular app to initiate a recompile, after which the 'deleted' images still displayed.

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Double check path with a <img src="<?php echo $name; ?>"> if the path was written correct?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about dev mode, using `ng serve`.  When you modify the `assets` folder, you usually need to stop and restart `ng serve`, not just making a change to restart compilation.

I'd advise that you keep the `assets` folder for static assets that wont be modified, and have another folder for images that may change dynamically over time.